# How do you prevent the base class constructor from being called with Moq?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

How do you prevent the base class constructor from being called with Moq?

I'm unable to Mock an object with Moq because the base classes constructor is being called and it requires real objects, so I want to stop the base class constructor from being called.

```
var parametersMoq = new Mock<MyDerivedClass>(null, "Params", null){ CallBase = false, };
_storedProcedureAccessor._parameters = parametersMoq.Object;
```

MyDerivedClass's base class constructor is causing me issues.

Comment: Do you have control over the base class? What are the constructor signatures of the base and derived classes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no way to prevent the base class constructor from being invoked.

If you can edit the base class, you should replace the fixed dependencies with abstractions (e.g. an interface, abstract class or a delegate).

If you can't edit the base class, and you really need to be able to substitute the dependencies with test friendly fakes to write your unit tests, you need to do a bit more work (e.g. wrap the problematic base class in an abstraction, then use composition instead of inheritence, and depend on the new abstraction).