# Moq: setup a constructor of a base class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, dbcontext

I use Entity Framework in my ASP.NET project and I have to setup `ApplicationDbContext` constructor in this way:

```
public ApplicationDbContext()
    : base(DBUtils.Configuration.GetConnection(), false)
{
}
```

`DBUtils.Configuration.GetConnection()` returns an instance of `DbConnection` with all proper settings (e.g. connection string). `ApplicationDbContext` is inserting in every service constructor with `Ninject`.

It works perfectly but it make some problems during writing test methods. In others projects (with a default `ApplicationDbContext` constructor) I just mocked database object like this: `db = new Mock<ApplicationDbContext>()` in `[TestInitialize]` method:

```
[TestClass]
public class MyServiceTest
{
    private MyService _service;
    private Mock<ApplicationDbContext> _db;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        _db = new Mock<ApplicationDbContext>();
    }

    //test methods
}
```

But now I need to insert `DbConnection` (probably by `DBUtils.Configuration.GetConnection()`, right?) to `:base()` of constructor in `ApplicationDbContext` and I cannot foind any solution how to do it. Simply assigned like:

```
[TestInitialize]
public void Initialize()
{
    _db = new Mock<ApplicationDbContext>();
    _db.Object.Database.Connection = DBUtils.Configuration.GetConnection();
}
```

or

```
[TestMethod]
public void Some_Test_Method()
{
    //...do stuff...
    _db.Setup(x => x.Database.Connection).Returns(DBUtils.Configuration.GetConnection());
    //...do stuff...
}
```

is obviously not working.

If I not apply connection in test class I get exception: *Failed to find or load the registered .Net Framework Data Provider* for every test method with stack trace:

```
Result StackTrace:  
in System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(DataRow providerRow)   
   in System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(String providerInvariantName)    
   in DBUtils.Configuration.GetConnection(String providerName)    
   in Invoices.Models.ApplicationDbContext..ctor() w C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Invoice\Invoices\Models\IdentityModels.cs:line 61    
   in Castle.Proxies.ApplicationDbContextProxy..ctor(IInterceptor[] )
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Where line 61 is exactly `: base(DBUtils.Configuration.GetConnection(), false)`

So the question is: how can I insert an instance of my `DbConnection` into `:base()` in Moq project?

**@EDIT:**

Everything working if I modify `ApplicationDbContext` constructor in this way:

```
public ApplicationDbContext()
    : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
{
    try
    {
        var connectionString = DBUtils.Configuration.GetConnection().ConnectionString;

        this.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
        this.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //log exception here
    }
}
```

But like I said before: I would rather setup database connection by inserting them into constructor.

Comment: If you mock a class with moq, the constructor will be called automatically. So the base class constructor will also be called, where you supply `DBUtils.Configuration.GetConnection()` as parameter.

Comment: @wimh Thanks for your response. I thought that it should be working like you said, but it doesn't - I still get exception `Failed to find or load the registered .Net Framework Data Provider`. I will update my question with some additional information. Give my a sec.

Comment: Did you try to debug the unit test? And for example set a breakpoint at the constructor? Maybe `DBUtils.Configuration.GetConnection()` is not returning a valid data provider in you unit tests. You might want to mock that. But if you found a way to not call the constructor in moq, you can answer it at [How do you prevent the base class constructor from being called with Moq?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10655431/33499)

Comment: @wimh Yes, I've debugging - `_db.Object` throw exception *Failed to find or load the registered .Net Framework Data Provider*, `DBUtils.Configuration.GetConnection()` is not calling in my unit test anywhere because I don't know how (and where) to do it. In project it provide valid data.

Comment: So the exception is thrown in the constructor inside `DBUtils.Configuration.GetConnection()`. So you should not call that in your unit tests. (Which makes sense, as you don't have a database in your unit tests). You should probably create an interface for `ApplicationDbContext`, and depend on that interface instead of the class itself. An interface is easier to moq, because there is no constructor which will be called.